# If statement not evaluating TRUE when it should

Tags: c++, numerical-methods, numerical-analysis

I have an array of "x" values (a grid for a PDE solver) that when I pass to a function that fills another array based on these x-values, a particular expression involving one x-value does not evaluate properly.  The x-values range is -1:1 at an increment of 0.0125, and at x = -0.5, and at x = 0.5, I need to handle these cases differently than the other values.  However the block below fails to evaluate to TRUE for the point x = 0.5 (it's ok for x = -0.5).  Here's a stripped down snippet of the problem block, with details to follow:

```
int N = 160;
double delta_x = 0.0125;
const double lims = 0.5 * delta_x;

for(int i = 0; i <= N; i++)
{                                
  if((x[i] < -0.5) || (x[i] > 0.5)) sol[i] = 0;
  else if( (abs(x[i] + 0.5) < lims) || (abs(x[i] - 0.5) < lims) )  sol[i] = 0.5;
  else sol[i] = 1;

  cout << setprecision(30) << "lims: " << lims << ", abs(x[i] - 0.5): " << abs(x[i] - 0.5) << endl;
  cout << "sol[" << i << "]: " << sol[i] << endl;                                                                                         
}
```

Here is the output for x = 0.5:

```
lims: 0.00625000000000000034694469519536, abs(x[i] - 0.5): 1.11022302462515654042363166809e-16
sol[120]: 0
```

So, it's looks like the expression in the if-statement should return TRUE when x = 0.5, even though it's not precisely 0.5 of course, since it is within the "lims" of the range.  Any thoughts??

Comment: That sure looks like an off-by-one bug to me.  Surely it should be < N instead of <= N?

Comment: Just checking -- are you including `cmath.h`? `abs` is only overloaded for doubles in that, `stdlib` declares int-only `abs`.

Comment: Please clarify what's not working as you expect.  In the example output, 1e-16 is certainly within the tolerance `lims`.

Comment: @HansPassant, The variable "N" is the number of x-values starting from 0, so the range of x-values are x_0:x_N for N+1 total array elements.  Thanks

Comment: I don't have that many neurons left, but one of the five is permanantly wired to flash madly whenever I see "<=" instead of just "<" in a C/C++/Java for loop.  Not that such code must be wrong, just likely that it is.

Comment: @David: I don't understand. The output you posted clearly shows that the `if` **is** entered for `x = 0.5`. What made you think that it is not entered? On the contrary, I don't see any output for `x = -0.5`. Yet you claim that `x = -0.5` "works". So what is all that supposed to mean?

Comment: @Jongware My include line is #include <cmath> -- Correct me if I'm wrong but I think that's the same as #include "cmath.h"?

Comment: The cause of this is most definitely that `abs(int)` is called. Just replace `abs` with `fabs`.

Comment: @Paul Groke: If `abs(int)` was called, then how did he manage to obtain `1.11022302462515654042363166809e-16` output after sending the result of `abs` to `cout`???

Comment: #include <cmath> is just the C++ header of #include <math.h>, so you are doing that right. Are you linking it as wel?

Comment: I have a strong suspicion that the OP either missed the `e-16` suffix in the output or simply doesn't know what that `e-16` means. I see no other explanation for his claim that `x = 0.5` skips the `if`, when the output clearly shows that `if` is entered.

Comment: @AndreyT: Good question. In don't know. :-) I just know that his code works with `fabs`, and there is no "off by one" error. See http://ideone.com/8aMIUO

Comment: Note that in both `if` statements you could remove two-thirds of the parentheses without changing the meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer to the original question**

The expression in the `if` statement did evaluate true. If it did not, then you would not have seen the output that you included in the question.

FWIW, a simpler test would be for

```
abs(abs(x[i]) - 0.5) < lims
```

**Answer to the latest version of the question**

```
if((x[i] < -0.5) || (x[i] > 0.5)) sol[i] = 0;
else if( (abs(x[i] + 0.5) < lims) || (abs(x[i] - 0.5) < lims) )  sol[i] = 0.5;
else sol[i] = 1;
```

You state that `x[i]` is close to 0.5, but does not set `sol[i]` to 0.5 and in fact sets it to `0`. In which case the only sane conclusion is that `x[i] > 0.5` and the first condition is is met:

```
if((x[i] < -0.5) || (x[i] > 0.5)) sol[i] = 0;
```

So you need to change the order of your tests:

```
if( (abs(x[i] + 0.5) < lims) || (abs(x[i] - 0.5) < lims) )  sol[i] = 0.5;
else if((x[i] < -0.5) || (x[i] > 0.5)) sol[i] = 0;
else sol[i] = 1;
```

And I would write it like this:

```
if (abs(abs(x[i]) - 0.5) < lims)
    sol[i] = 0.5;
else if ((x[i] < -0.5) || (x[i] > 0.5)) 
    sol[i] = 0;
else 
    sol[i] = 1;
```

---

Please in future be sure to include the right code in the question that you ask.

Comment: Exactly. The output quoted in the question was generated for `x = 0.5`. Yet the OP claims that for `x = 0.5` the `if` is not entered. The question, as stated, is contradicting itself.

Comment: @AndreyT Thanks for noticing that, my mistake.  I was trying to make it simpler but then it wasn't showing the error.  I just edited it so that the error results.

Comment: @David Heffernon - Thanks!  I just realized I need to simply check that problem if-statement first.

Comment: Leaving out the headers for brevity added a layer to the confusion as well. Mistaking `abs` for `fabs` is, alas, a common mistake -- and, as I just tested, `-Wall` on `printf("%f", abs(1.5));` only warns for the `%f`, not for the implicit conversion to int.

Answer (score 1):

Well, now after you corrected your code, the problem is obvious. For `x[i] = 0.5` the control is intercepted by the very first condition

```
if((x[i] < -0.5) || (x[i] > 0.5)) sol[i] = 0;
```

It doesn't even get to your `abs` evaluations.

Floating-point number are not always precise. While it is true that `0.5` can be represented precisely, it only applies to situations when you assign `0.5` directly or use some simple and particularly stable evaluations to arrive at that value (like in case of `1.0/2`). In more complex cases you might end up with imprecise `0.5` value (like in case of `0.1 * 5`). And that is what's causing it to get intercepted by that first `if`. Your positive `0.5` is imprecise and just happens to be greater than the precise `0.5`.

One way to fix it might be to put your approximate `lim`-based comparisons first and make "precise" comparisons follow

```
if( (abs(x[i] + 0.5) < lims) || (abs(x[i] - 0.5) < lims) )  sol[i] = 0.5; 
else if((x[i] < -0.5) || (x[i] > 0.5)) sol[i] = 0;
else sol[i] = 1;
```